# Redux accessing state from action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

I've read multiple sources online suggesting to avoid accessing state wherever possible in your actions, however I would like to know whether its acceptable to do so when checking if data already exists in my state before making another asynchronous request? Currently I have this in my action:

```
export const setCategory = (id) => {
    const state = store.getState();
    const categories = state.display.categories;
    const category = categories.find(category => category.id === id);
    const categoryVids = category ? category.videos : {};
    if(Object.keys(categoryVids).length <= 0) { 
        return dispatch => {
            //Do some async stuff
        }
    }
}
```

To me it seems more logical to access state here. Would it be considered better practice to move this logic to the component?

Comment: Just a warning, `const categoryVids = categories.find(category => category.id === id).videos;` will error when it doesn't find any matching category. You are essentially calling `undefined.videos`.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda Ah yes, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: And just my two cents, I think in this example it makes sense to check the current state. Sounds like you want to pre-load category data when the user switches categories.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your action creators should generally be pure functions that don't result in side effects. The reason you don't want to access state in your action creator is because that means the result of `setCategory()` cannot be predicted based on its arguments. The whole point of Redux is to be able to reason about the state of your application in a straightforward way. If you can't easily follow the change in state that resulted from a given action being dispatched, that becomes much harder.

When you need to conditionally dispatch an action based on whether some part of state exists or not, then it's clearer to do that in "client" code (i.e. the client from Redux's perspective), which in this case would probably be a component. You can do the check and then dispatch some kind of `LOAD_DATA` action if the data is missing.

However, if you need to do something asynchronous, then you should investigate common patterns for [async operations](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions) in Redux, or use an existing library, like [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) or [`redux-saga`](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga).

Comment: See the Motivation section on the Redux Thunk homepage for an example of how that library handles checking state inside an action creator - the `getState()` function is provided as the second argument to a thunk.

Comment: No, action creators are absolutely allowed to be impure and have side effects. _Reducers_ must be pure.  Beyond that, please see my post [Idiomatic Redux: Thoughts on Thunks, Sagas, Abstraction, and Reusability](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/idiomatic-redux-thoughts-on-thunks-sagas-abstraction-and-reusability/) for more thoughts on why it's okay to access state in action creators.  Thunks are also the best place to do conditional dispatching, specifically because they can access the entire state tree (whereas a component only has the specific props it extracted in `mapState` ).

Answer (score 2):

Your code is sort of on the right track, but you should write the entire thing as a thunk, because then it has access to `getState` directly:

```
export const setCategory = (id) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const state = getState();
        const {categories} = state.display;
        const category = categories.find(category => category.id === id) || {};
        const {videos : categoryVids = {} } = category;

        if(Object.keys(categoryVids).length >= 0) {
            // dispatch here
        }
    }
}
```